# pyqt identify a client socket and send response data only to it

Tags: sockets, pyqt

I am new to PyQt and socket programming,I found some code on the Internet and I almost understand it.In the server side code,the server would return data to all the clients,which is desirable because it's a chat program.What I want to do is identify which which client requested the server,and let the server return data only to that client.

Now my idea is like this,identify the client by using `socketDescriptor()`,and the server send the response data along with an extra `socketDescriptor()`.Then the client side would compare its `socketDescriptor()` with the one it received if it's the same it do something with the data,if not it do nothing.But in this way I essentially send data to all clients.

First,I don't know if I am on the right track.Second,can I send data from the server to only one client instead of all?

And here is the server side code:

```
import sys
import datetime
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *

PORT = 9999
SIZEOF_UINT32 = 4

class ServerDlg(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ServerDlg, self).__init__(
                "&Close Server", parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        self.tcpServer = QTcpServer(self)
        self.tcpServer.listen(QHostAddress("0.0.0.0"), PORT)
        self.connect(self.tcpServer, SIGNAL("newConnection()"),
                    self.addConnection)
        self.connections = []
        self.messageRecord = []

        self.connect(self, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.close)
        font = self.font()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setWindowTitle("Server")

    def addConnection(self):
        clientConnection = self.tcpServer.nextPendingConnection()
        clientConnection.nextBlockSize = 0
        self.connections.append(clientConnection)

        self.connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL("readyRead()"),
                self.receiveMessage)
        self.connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL("disconnected()"),
                self.removeConnection)
        self.connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL("error()"),
                self.socketError)

 def receiveMessage(self):
        for s in self.connections:
            if s.bytesAvailable() > 0:
                stream = QDataStream(s)
                stream.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_4_2)

                if s.nextBlockSize == 0:
                    if s.bytesAvailable() < SIZEOF_UINT32:
                        return
                    s.nextBlockSize = stream.readUInt32()
                if s.bytesAvailable() < s.nextBlockSize:
                    return

                textFromClient = stream.readQString()
                s.nextBlockSize = 0
                self.sendMessage(textFromClient,
                                 s.socketDescriptor())
                s.nextBlockSize = 0

    def sendMessage(self, text, socketId):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        for s in self.connections:
            if s.socketDescriptor() == socketId:
                message = "<p>"+str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + "</p>" +  "<font color=red>You</font> > {}".format(text)
            else:
                message = "<p>"+str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + "</p>" + "<font color=green>{}</font> > {}".format(socketId, text)
            msRecorded = "<p>"+str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + "</p>" + "<font color=green>{}</font> > {}".format(socketId, text)
            self.messageRecord.append(msRecorded)
            reply = QByteArray()
            stream = QDataStream(reply, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
            stream.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_4_2)
            stream.writeUInt32(0)
            stream.writeQString(message)
            stream.device().seek(0)
            stream.writeUInt32(reply.size() - SIZEOF_UINT32)
            s.write(reply)

    def removeConnection(self):
        pass

    def socketError(self):
        pass


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = ServerDlg()
form.show()
form.move(0, 0)
app.exec_()
```

Thanks,G

Answer (score 1):

It looks like every time one connection emits a `readyRead()`, you go and loop through all the connections each time. It would be a lot better if you only dealt with the one that is emitting the signal.

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with all of this, but here are a couple things you can try:

#### Index your connections by their socket id

Instead of storing your connections in a list, you could store them in a dict with their socket id as a key. This way you don't have to loop over your entire list every time you want to work with just one:

```
self.connections = {}

...

def addConnection(self):
    conn = self.tcpServer.nextPendingConnection()
    self.connections[conn.socketDescriptor()] = conn

...

def sendMessage(self, text, socketId):
    conn = self.connections[socketId]
```

#### Asking for the sender in the SLOT

Though this is considered less pythonic, you also have the option of just asking what QObject is the sender of the signal that is reaching your SLOT

```
self.connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL("readyRead()"),
                self.receiveMessage)

...

def receiveMessage(self):
    conn = self.sender()
```

#### Create self contained client objects

You could just create your own Connection class, store the QTcpSocket on it when you get a new connection, and connect its signals to handlers inside that Connection class you made. Then you can emit your own custom signals from it that identify the connection. There are a number of ways you could design this really.